# I have some issues while making an slideshow

Tags: html, css, slide

I'm trying to make an slideshow, but when it moves to the next (or previous) image, there is nothing on the background.

I would like the image you're going to see appearing behind the one you are seeing, something like when you are shuffling cards.

Aditionally, I would like to have different animations when you click on the right or on the left arrow, to match it's movement.

Here is the code I'm using right now:

[Code](https://codepen.io/gudbais/pen/rXMovP)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

 <div class="mySlides animated slideInLeft">
  <img src="https://pruebas20.webcindario.com/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides animated slideInRight">
  <img src="https://pruebas20.webcindario.com/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides slideInRight">
  <img src="https://pruebas20.webcindario.com/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
 </div>

 <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are hiding all but the current slide, both with javascript and css.

```js
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
```

```css
.mySlides {display: none}
```

You would need to remove this, but change the z-index of the slides instead so that the current slide is on top, and at the same time add the slideInRight/slideInLeft classes. You would also need to absolutely position the slides within the container, so that they occupy the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mark Fisher is correct. You need to play around with the z-index of the slides. To be honest it would probably be easier to use a plugin such as [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) if you want to have cool transitions etc. 
I have created a codepen based on your code. It is not perfect, but perhaps you can get an idea of how to do this. Your slides need to be positioned absolutely within the slide wrapper in order to be "revealed" behind each other when you move between slides. I have used a CSS transition on the position to animate the slide.

```
.mySlides {position: absolute; left: 0; z-index: 0;transition: left 1s linear; width: 300px; height: 105px;}
```

https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/eqdXby